# SQL query to delete records containing

Tags: sql, prestashop

I have a Prestashop installation with several unnecessary language registrations.

I have already removed all languages, but the generated records still persist.

I need to delete all rows from all tables that have column id_lang with a value other than 6 and then change all tables that have id_lang equal to 6 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

To delete:

```
delete from TABLENAME where id_lang != 6
```

To update:

```
update TABLENAME set id_lang=1 where id_lang=6
```